# Power BI: Query parameters in an embed request

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

Does anyone know of a way in Power BI to set query parameters as described [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/) from an embed request instead of inside desktop? We are attempting to setup a system where we use power bi to power visualizations within our app for customers to view their data. We need to use some sort of parameter system to insure that the query returns the proper customer data for the visualization.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Row Level Security for this job. 
It's pretty simple, let say that in your fact table you have already information about your customer. You can create a role in PBI Desktop that filter the data for the specific user loged-in using the USERNAME() DAX formula. Then when pushing your pbix in the PBI Service your can associate role with user... and you are done.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should create new measures in your report and use formula of a role, ex:

IF (
    **USERPRINCIPALNAME()** = "test@test.com",
     --- some condition  ---
)

or you can use **USERNAME()**.